# Allow spaces only at the start and end of the string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regExp that allow spaces only at the start and end of the string and disallow in the middle. Also forbidden is `<>#%` characters.
**Update**:
Current regExp func is:

```
(value: string) => {
    const disalowedCharacters = [' ', '<', '>', '#', '%', '{', '}', '|', '\\',
      '^', '~', '[', ']', '`', ';', '/', '?', ':', '@', '=', '&', '$', '\n'];
    const regExp = new RegExp(`[${escapeRegExp(disalowedCharacters.join(''))}]`);
    const isValid = !regExp.test(value);
    return isValid ? [] : [`The URL can't contain space, newline, and the following
      characters < > # % { } | \\ ^ ~ [ ] \` ; / ? : @ = & $`];
  };
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

`^\s?([^\s<>#%]*)\s?$`

https://regexfiddler.com/e/u1fn6qn6z93s/check-string-does-not-contain-spaces